# Storing in MySQL relationships between different type of objects

Tags: architecture, database-design, data-structures, mysql, laravel

I have an app that needs to attach objects of different types between them. For example: I have to add `Lead` type object to a `Contact` type object , a `Contact` to an `Event` and so on.

Such relationship looks to me to be an undirected graph (If `Car A` is attached to `Contact B` has same meaning with  `Contact B` is considered to be attached to `Car A`).

`Car A` edge `Contact B`  means two things:
- `Car A` is attached to  `Contact B`
- `Contact B` is attached to `Car A`

Those two meanings are not independent, they are the same "business", only a different point of view

**Question**: What is the best way of storing such relationships in a SQL database (MySQL - my case)

**Sidenote**: I use Eloquent ORM (Laravel/PHP) and using a pivot table (for many to many relation types)  for each type of relationship partially works, as it does not work when you try to make relation between same objects: `Contact` `<->` `Contacts`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have a relationship between objects in the same table.

For example, I have a `services` table and services can have a BelongsToMany relationship with one or more other services.  Like a Database service is a dependency for the CRM Service and the Finance Service but also requires the Storage and Network services.

Use a pivot table, such as the following:

```
Schema::create('service_dependencies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->integer('service_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('dependency_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('service_id')->references('id')->on('services');
        $table->foreign('dependency_id')->references('id')->on('services');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->primary(array('service_id', 'dependency_id', 'type'));
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

You can see that both the service_id and dependency_id are actually the `id` on the `services` table.

The `Service` model looks like this:

```
public function get_supported_services() {
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\Service', 'dependency_service', 'service_id', 'dependency_id')
        ->withPivot('type')
        ->wherePivot('type','supports')
        ->orderBy('service_short_name');
}

public function get_required_services ()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\Service', 'dependency_service', 'service_id', 'dependency_id')
        ->withPivot('type')
        ->wherePivot('type','requires')
        ->orderBy('service_short_name');
}
```

Comment: Looking at your solutions , it seems to me that you have an oriented graph : when you add a Service A to a Service B, there are two edges between these two nodes: `get_supported_services`, `get_required_services`

Comment: That is because I need to manage the direction of the relationship.  I'm not familiar with oriented graph, but is Service A is added as 'required' for Service B, it can't also have a second relationship that is Service B 'supports' Service A.  So not sure if you would say that there are two edges between the two nodes.   If direction wasn't important, it would only need a `get_services`.